# Cannot build app on an iphone "No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version."

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to test my app on an iPhone 4s, but I'm getting this error:

"No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

Note that:

The 4s has version 7.1 Beta2 of iOS installed
The iOS deployment target is set to version 7.0
The device has valid development profiles installed
I'm using the latest Xcode 5.0.2

At Xcode > Window > Organizer, I got this message:

"The version of iOS on “my device name” is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on 'my device name'
7.1 (11D5115d)"

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install apps onto a device running a developer preview OS, you'll also need to get the latest Xcode developer preview (from http://developer.apple.com/ios ) and build and install with that.

Comment: Thanks. I see it now. At first I didn't notice that there was SDK for iOS 7 beta 2.

Comment: i have iOS 7.1 (which is not previous anymore) and have mavericks/updated Xcode (5.0.2), but it still says i need to download sdk... I would have thought it would come with the Xcode update?? Cheers